# преобразование массивов

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть массив `arr = [["a"], ["b"], ["c"], ["d"], ["e"], ["f"]]` .

Как преобразовать его в `[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ну можно просто в лоб

```js
  arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
  
  res = [[]];
  
  arr.forEach((obj, index) => {
    res[res.length - 1].push(obj);
    
    if ((index % 2 === 1) && (index < arr.length - 1))
        res.push([]);
  });

  console.log(res);
```

можно еще в лоб, но покороче

```js
  arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
  
  res = [];
  
  for (let index = 0; index < arr.length / 2; index ++)
    res.push(arr.slice(index * 2, index * 2 + 2));
  
  console.log(res);
```

можно покороче, но тоже в лоб

```js
  arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
  
  res = [];
  
  for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index += 2)
    res.push([arr[index], arr[index + 1]]);
  
  console.log(res);
```

Тут возникло подозрение, а не имел ли автор в виду

```
arr = [["a"], ["b"], ["c"], ["d"], ["e"], ["f"]]
```

Тогда решение схожее, к примеру:

```js
  arr = [["a"], ["b"], ["c"], ["d"], ["e"], ["f"]]

  res = []
  
  for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index += 2)
    res.push([arr[index][0], arr[index + 1][0]]);
  
  console.log(res);
```

Comment: в вопросе исходный массив по другому выглядит

Comment: @Grundy: угу, в вопросе ещё и типы данных преобразовать надо ))

Comment: @Grundy, а так массив можно задать? - у меня ошибку выдает, поэтому предположил, что автор привел просто значение элементов одномерного массива

Comment: @Zhihar, забавно, не заметил что там запятых нет между элементами :) если добавить запятые и обернуть в квадратные скобки - можно

Comment: @Grundy, тогда непонятно, что же именно имел в виду автор, но если `[[], [], []]`, то решение по сути отличаться от приведенного не должно, маленький допил надо сделать только

Comment: @Zhihar: "нужно больше золота..."

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Изначально массив такого вида arr = [["a"], ["b"], ["c"], ["d"], ["e"], ["f"]] Типы данных преобразовывать не надо.

Answer (score 0):

В Lodash есть функция которая делает то что вам нужно https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chunk

В этой библиотеке вы сможете найти множество готовых решений

```
_.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 2);
// => [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]

_.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 3);
// => [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

Comment: исходный массив другой

Comment: спасибо за уточнение, поправил

Comment: У него структура другая, а не только значения: `[[],[],[], ...]` а у тебя просто плоский

Answer (score -1):

Решение немного нетривиальное

```
const arr = [["a"], ["b"], ["c"], ["d"], ["e"], ["f"], ["g"]];
console.log(arr.flat().filter((v,i)=>!(i%2)).map((v,i)=>[v,...(arr[2*i+1]||[,])]));
// => [ 0: ["a", "b"], 
//      1: ["c", "d"], 
//      2: ["e", "f"], 
//      3: ["g", undefined ] ]
```

Comment: решение не тривиальное но рабоает только с массивами в которых четное количество элементов.

Comment: @VasiliAnoshin может, и работает с массивами, в которых четное количество элементов, зато вашего решения я не вижу тут.

Comment: я бы добавил проверкку на undefined.

Comment: @VasiliAnoshin, проверка стоит. можно туда поставить любое значение, но стоит именно это `[,]`. Оно и есть тот undefined.

Comment: В нечетном массиве должно выходить // 3: ["g" ]]. Если у тебя нету возможности построить пару посл. массив будет состоять из оного элемента.

Comment: @VasiliAnoshin для этого можно убрать запятую между скобками `[,]` чтобы было так `[]`.